# If $G$ and $H$ are two groups with the same order and both are abelian, then they are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following statement True or False? If $G$ and $H$ are two groups with the same order and both are abelian, then they are isomorphic.

I think  the answer is false, but I do not know how to prove it. Can anyone help me on how to go about doing it?

Comment: Try groups of order 4.

Comment: As Ihf says $Z_4$ and $Z_2 \times Z_2.$

Comment: For finite groups this is only true if the order is prime.

Answer (score 2):

It is false: consider the cyclic group of order 4 and [Klein 4-group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).

Answer (score 1):

To disprove the statement you have to find a counterexample, that is, two Abelian groups with the same number of elements that are not isomorphic. As a hint, try to find (Abelian) groups with four elements.